# What is encode type of this text "\u0110\u0103ng nh\u1eadp"?

Tags: java, encode

This code was generated from Vietnamese by somebody. I need change this Vietnamese text for business. So what encode type of this text "u0110\u0103ng nh\u1eadp". More text:

```
## Page titles
page.login.title=\u0110\u0103ng nh\u1eadp
page.metadata.title=Thu\u1ed9c t\u00ednh

# Form loading messages
message.saving=L\u01b0u d\u1eef li\u1ec7u
message.saved=D\u1eef li\u1ec7u \u0111\u01b0\u1ee3c l\u01b0u
message.save-failure=Kh\u00f4ng th\u1ec3 l\u01b0u d\u1eef li\u1ec7u
```

Comment: I am using java, alfresco framework java 1.8, alfresco v5.2

Comment: that file is .properties in .jar file, i must trans some text in this framework into my language

Comment: Each `\uXXXX` sequence represents a Unicode character, where `XXXX` is the character number in hexadecimal.  So `\u0110` is Unicode character 0x0110 (decimal 272) which from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF is the character **Đ**, and so on.  That first string is **Đăng nhập**.  Your file looks like a straightforward Java localization Properties file.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html for a quick intro to those files. The format is exactly what it looks like: message names are matched with localised text.